# Get Location from redirected URL's header

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I need to get the redirect URL from an API call using retrofit.
If I'm testing the url with `Postman` it gives back the Header and I can see the URL in it. This is how I build my retrofit:

```
    private static Interceptor interceptor = chain -> {
    okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    Log.d("REDIRECT","to"+response.header("Location"));
    return response;
};

public static NetworkInterface getNetworkInterface() {
    if (networkInterface == null) {
        serverGson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                .followRedirects(true)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(serverGson))
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();
        networkInterface = retrofit.create(NetworkInterface.class);
    }
    return networkInterface;
}
```

And this my API call:

```
    Disposable api = Server.getNetworkInterface().oAuthUser("param",
            "param","param",
            "param","param")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(response-> {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String responseHeader = response.headers().toString();
                        Log.d("auth header",responseHeader);
                    }
            }, error-> {
                error.printStackTrace();
            });
```

This what I get back:

`2019-03-29 14:55:35.935 22434-22434/com.package.app W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to BASEURL/IP ADDRESS`

It's okay because the second URL where I should be redirected it's not pointing anywhere so if I call it I should get back this. But for the fist time I call the valid URL and postman gives back `302 Found` so I think when retrofit get back this trying to call the URL but it does not work so I get back this error message.

The problem is that in the error case I should see the second URL where I should be redirected and not the first URL. How can I get the second URL in the onFailure case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by disabling redirect and this I'm getting back the response in `onResponse` and it's contains the the URL in the message.

```
   .followRedirects(false)
```